# File Increment returning null with static variable

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I want to increment the file version. I have declared a static variable of 10 and i want it to increment from 10 to 11 , 12 , 13.....every time when you click save

**XML file:**

```
<resheader name="version">
    <value>10</value>
</resheader>
<resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</resheader>
```

**Method:**

```
public void VesrionInc()
{
    lblversion.Visible = true;
    int updateversion = 1000;
    updateversion++;
    XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();

    string xmlcontents = _doc.InnerXml;
    lblversion.Text = updateversion.ToString();

    XmlNode root = _doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value");
    myNode.InnerText = updateversion.ToString();
    lblversion.Text = updateversion.ToString();
}
```

When i debug it shows increment but, when it reads this code below. it is breaking on the second line, it became null and when i push F5 it say, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
XmlNode root = _doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode =    root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value"); //it breaks here
myNode.InnerText = updateversion.ToString();
lblversion.Text = updateversion.ToString();
```

**Save button:**

```
private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iversion = Convert.ToInt32(lblversion.Text.ToString());

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(outputFilePath);
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList CnodesList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::data");


    XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value");
    //myNode.InnerText = iversion.ToString(lblversion.Text);
    myNode.InnerText = iversion.ToString();
    lblversion.Text = iversion.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss document loading in the VesrionInc() method.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare XmlDocument _doc, but this document is empty. You must insert into document any data by method

XmlDocument.**Load()** = data from file, FileStream or XmlReader :

```
_doc.Load("c:\\xmlsamle.xml");
```

XmlDocument.**LoadXml()** = Insert xml structure from string :

```
_doc.LoadXml("<resheader name='version'><value>10</value></resheader>");
```

I hope the above xml file is not complete. If so, you have in xml two root elements, and it could be a problem too. I recommend xml correction:

```
<resheader>
     <version>10</version>
     <reader>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</reader>
</resheader>
```

XPath will then be:

```
...
XmlNode root = _doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("version");
...
```

I hope I helped you